# Implode array giving out error

Tags: php, arrays, insert, implode

I'm trying to implode an array to perform insertion , but i couldn't trigger the error i did.
*implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed*
*Please note my array size is not fix so i used foreach*

Array structure

```
[attcode] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) 
[color] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) 
[size] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) 
[stock] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )
```

Working code

```
    $attstring = array();//array for storing query set

    foreach($productcount['attcode'] as $attcode){
            $attstring[] = "'" . implode("','", $attcode)."'";
            }

        foreach($productcount['color'] as $attcolor){

            $attstring[] = "'" . implode("','", $attcolor)."'";
            }

    foreach($productcount['size'] as $attsize){
            $attstring[] = "'" . implode("','", $attsize)."'";
            }

    foreach($productcount['stock'] as $attstock){
            $attstring[] = "'" . implode("','", $attstock) . "'";
            }


    $finalvalue = "(" . implode("), (", $attstring) . ")";

            echo $finalvalue;
```

Desired output

```
('code','color','size',stock),
('code','color','size',stock),
('code','color','size',stock)
```

Comment: Id be curious to see the ACTUAL array layout. is 0, 1, 2 the values? the keys?

Comment: the implode in the foreach blocks are wrong, because you are not passing an array

Comment: The foreach is iterating over the array, so $attcode is a string, not an array, which is why implode isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array structure does not fit the desired output format. So implode won't work.

```
<?php

$my_array = ARRAY();
$my_array['attcode'] = Array ( 0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 2);
$my_array['color'] = Array ( 0 => 'red', 1 => 'green', 2 => 'blue');
$my_array['size'] = Array ( 0 => 100, 1 => 200, 2 => 300);
$my_array['stock'] = Array ( 0 => 11, 1 => 22, 2 => 33);

$loop_me = count($my_array['attcode']) - 1; 
for ($i=0; $i<=$loop_me; $i++) {
  echo '<div>Code: '.$my_array['attcode'][$i].' | Color: '.$my_array['color'][$i].' | Size: '.$my_array['size'][$i].' | Stock: '.$my_array['stock'][$i].'</div>';
}

?>
```

Output

```
Code: 0 | Color: red | Size: 100 | Stock: 11 |
Code: 1 | Color: green | Size: 200 | Stock: 22 |
Code: 2 | Color: blue | Size: 300 | Stock: 33 |
```

Comment: I think this answer would be even better if you make the for loop `for ($i=0, $j=count($my_array['attcode']); $i<$j; $i++)`.

Comment: Yes, right, thought wrong there are only 3, but what is fixed is the array indexes attcode, color, size, stock ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
implode(',', $productcount['attcode']);
//same for others
```

Answer (score 0):

implode works with arrays not it's values, it appends the desired string with array elements. You are passing array value to implode. pls check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for detail

Answer (score 0):

You left out the most important part of the error message; where it says that implode expects an array and that you've passed a string. Based on the desired output, I reckon you want something like this:

```
<?php

$productcount = array( 
    'attcode' => array ( '0', '1', '2' ),
    'color' => array ( 'red', 'green', 'blue' ),
    'size' => array( '0', '1', '2' ),  
    'stock' => array ( 100, 200, 300 )
);

$outcome = array( );

foreach( $productcount['attcode'] as $index => $code ) {
    $outcome[] = array(
        'attcode' => $code,
        'color' => isset( $productcount['color'][$index] ) ? $productcount['color'][$index] : null,
        'size' => isset( $productcount['size'][$index] ) ? $productcount['size'][$index] : null,
        'stock' => isset( $productcount['stock'][$index] ) ? $productcount['stock'][$index] : null
    );
}

var_dump( $outcome );
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
$attstring = array();//array for storing query set

foreach($productcount as $attributeCount){
    $attstring[] = "'" . implode("','", $attributeCount)."'";
}

$finalvalue = "(" . implode("), (", $attstring) . ")";

echo $finalvalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've build the wrong array for the output you want:

```
$products = array();
$products[] = array('attrcode' => 'XXXX', 'color' => 'black', 'size' => '12', 'stock' => 'yes');
$products[] = array('attrcode' => 'XXXX', 'color' => 'white', 'size' => '5', 'stock' => 'no');

$imploded_products = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $imploded_products[] = "'".implode("','", $product)."'";
}

$finalvalue = "(".implode("), (", $imploded_products).")";

echo $finalvalue;
```